# how to attach two different types of events to the same element

Tags: javascript, html, events, keyboard-events

I am pretty new to js and I may logically be going about this all the wrong way.  I am trying to have my custom alert object close if someone either clicks the button, or hits the enter key.  But I have not been able to get it to work.

```
document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button id="OK" type="button" onkeypress="if (window.event.keyCode == 13){Alert.ok()}" onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
```

I have something similar for a textfield that works fine.  What is the difference between these?  I know it is messy to do it inline, but it is for a single wordpress page.

```
document.getElementById('dialogboxbody2').innerHTML = '<form><input type="text" id="zipcode" maxlength="5" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13){Alert.checkZip()}" autofocus /></form>';
```

Update:
I tried the follwing and it still didn't trigger the onkeypress event.

```
<button id="OK" type="button" onkeypress="key13(event)" onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>  

this.key13=function(event){
                  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
                  if (x == 13){
                    Alert.ok();
                  }
                }
```

Here is the link to CodePen http://codepen.io/enielsen0001/pen/XJxGaq

I cannot thank you all enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the first example you are trying to do **window**.event.keyCode, while in the second (which works) event.keyCode.

Answer (score 0):

on button event 'keypress' works after focus it.

(try 'Enter' after 'click' button, you see it works.)

> The onkeypress property sets and returns the onKeyPress event handler code for the **current element.**

[onkeypress MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress)

```js
var c = document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot')
c.innerHTML = '<button id="OK" type="button" style="width:100px;height:100px;" onkeypress="key13(event)" onclick="alert(true);">OK</button>';

function key13(event){
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode
  if (x == 13){
    alert('key press "Enter" after focus button" ');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogboxfoot" style="background:#CCC; width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
```